# Clang template incomplete type

Tags: c++, templates, clang

I have the following code that compiles fine under in Visual Studio and g++ but in Clang I get the error "error: 'ns::B' is an incomplete type"

A.h

```
#pragma once
namespace ns
{
    class B;

    class A
    {
        friend class B;
        class Inner
        {
        public:
            int x;
            Inner(int x) : x(x) {}
        };
    public:
        template<typename T>
        T getB(int i)
        {
            B b = B(Inner(i));
            return T(b);
        }

    };
}
```

B.h

```
#pragma once
#include "A.h"

namespace ns
{
    class B
    {
        A::Inner i;
    public:
        B(A::Inner i) : i(i)
        {}

        operator int() const
        {
            return i.x;
        }
    };
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "A.h"
#include "B.h"

int main()
{
    ns::A a;
    return a.getB<int>(5);
}
```

From my understanding the code should work because by the time the template get instantiated, B is complete. Is this correct? And if so, is there any way to work around the issue in Clang?

Comment: Unrelated side note: `#include "a.h"` in main.cpp is meaningless.

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall It's well and good to repeatedly include headers, but they must have include guards which aren't shown here.

Comment: @Potatoswatter Right sorry, I did miss those when copying.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required.

[[temp.res]/8](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.res#8):

> The program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required, if:
>
> - [...]
> - a hypothetical instantiation of a template immediately following its definition would be ill-formed due to a construct that does not depend on a template parameter, or
> - [...]

Comment: … so one solution is to only forward-declare `A::getB` in `A.h`, and define it in `B.h`.

Comment: @Potatoswatter awesome, thanks a lot. Do you have any idea why it would work in VS and g++?

Comment: @MikeJones: Visual doesn't do the 2 passes check for template (which is not standard compliant), and so doesn't check non dependent code. For g++, (which does the 2 passes check), they miss the opportunity to diagnose that.