# GCC vs clang: invalid use of incomplete type, who is right?

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, clang, language-lawyer

Consider the following snippet:

```
struct foo_t;

template<typename T>
void foo() {
    T{}.foo(foo_t{});
}

struct foo_t {};

struct S {
    void foo(foo_t) {}
};

int main() {
    foo<S>();
}
```

GCC happily [compiles it](https://wandbox.org/permlink/fWlrbmigCYimafgS) while clang [rejects the snippet](https://wandbox.org/permlink/4ZYeb0b9rY0jpN1f) with the following error:

> error: invalid use of incomplete type 'foo_t'

Which compiler is right and why?

Comment: I believe this is a dupe of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41713945/clang-template-incomplete-type) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37599877/why-an-incomplete-type-is-detected-in-clang-inside-a-template-method)

Comment: ^ - Yup. Was searching for answers that have *"a hypothetical instantiation of a template immediately following its definition..."* myself.

Comment: @NathanOliver one of the links is about MSVC, the other one involves multiple files. are you sure they can be considered dup?

Comment: Pretty sure.  They both have the answer.  Since `foo_t` does not depend on the template it has to be defined even though the template hasn't been instantiated yet.

Comment: The one about MSVC is basically the same as this except it MSVC vc Clang instead of GCC vs Clang

Comment: @NathanOliver I didn't know that, interesting indeed. Would it be correct then if `foo_t` was a template class?

Comment: @NathanOliver I mean, something along [this line](https://wandbox.org/permlink/jdQwrsIZKaHiGin2). Is it correct?

Comment: @skypjack Yep.  I just wrote that example myself ;) http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a9250ab2c43aaf1b

Comment: Since it depends on `T` then it waits until the second pass (instantiated) and it is complete then.

Comment: @NathanOliver Thank you very much for the explanation, it makes sense actually. Got it.